# I have error when i use datepicker for jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, twig

I have add datepicker for jQuery UI but I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

I add plugin jQuery and jQuery-ui but I have also error

code twig:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Acceuil-{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Raleway:400,700|Merriweather:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/MarkerCluster.css') }}">
            <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/MarkerCluster.Default.css') }}">
            <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{{ asset('bundles/app/css/application-42e4eacdbf0506bba5a7d1c783732309c84eb2d6203203da608691b414ebe1c7.css') }}">
        {% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            {% block header %}
                        <header id="navbar">
                            <div class="container">
                            <a class="logo nounou-top"  href="{{path('homePage')}}">BabySitter</a>

                            <div class="ui secondary user menu floated right">
                            <div id="connect_subscribe_links">

                            <a class="item" id="navbar_connect" href="{{path('fos_user_security_login')}}">Connexion</a>
                            <a class="ui small action button blue" id="navbar_subscribe" href="{{ path('inscription') }}">Inscription</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui dropdown autolaunch icon button right top pointing blue" id="connect_subscribe_menu">
                            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                            <div class="ui menu transition hidden">
                            <a class="item" href="/sessions/new">Connexion</a>
                            <a class="item" href="/welcome/choice_category_ad">Inscription</a>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </header>
            {% endblock %} 
            {% block body %}            


            {% endblock %}
         </div> 
        {% block javascripts %}
            <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/places.js') }}"></script>
            <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
            <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
            <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/application-5385288a7f4b3693dff01f301b0b54547c2887a2eaf0c85b91ed655ec7424ff7.js') }}"></script>
            <script src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/stripe.js') }}"></script>
            <script>
 $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } ); 
</script>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I add plugin jquery and jquery UI but I have this error .. how to resolve this error please

Comment: Check jquery and jquery ui registered in page or not

Comment: Jquery and jqueryui is registered in page

Comment: Put your code in jsfiddle

Comment: any help please

Comment: *datepicker is not a function* means that jQuery UI is not loaded or can't be read due to an error upstream. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve this should be the Resulting HTML not your behind the scene code.